# Does Adobe Reader 9 automatically update to Adobe Reader X?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I have Adobe Reader 9.4.1. Does it automatically update to X? If not, is it worth installing Adobe Reader X?

Comment: reader X won't overwrite reader 9 ! I've tried it ! As if they are separate programs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does it automatically update to X?

After a quick search I can't find anything that says that adobe reader 9 will automatically update to Reader X.

> is it worth installing Adobe Reader X?

According to Adobe's [site](http://www.adobe.com/products/reader/faq.html):

> Adobe Reader X adds much in the way of
>   new functionality, especially relating
>   to highlighting and commenting,
>   security, and enhanced user
>   experience.

Offline installer is here: ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/

Comment: ▲ for the direct link. Adobe DLM can die in a fire.

Comment: @grawity: I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

I had Adobe Reader 9 installed on my Vista system. Downloading and installing Reader X from Adobe's website replaced this older version (i.e. I now see "Adobe Reader X" where "Adobe Reader 9" used to be in Control Panel -> Programs, and I did not have to uninstall Reader 9 first). Also, checking for updates under version 9 did not show version X - it wanted to update me to some higher 9.x version. Didn't bother with that and just got X from adobe.com instead

Answer (score 0):

My CNET Tech Tracker Program alerted me to the fact that I needed an update ONLY for AVG.  When I logged in and opened my tracker page, it also showed that "Reader X" was "out of date".

So, because I didn't recognize the "X", I opened my current Reader 9.4.1 and selected "check for updates" under the HELP pulldown memu---the result was that there are "No Updates Available."    Sooooo- apparantly even Adobe doesn't consider "X" an "update" to 9.4.1.

I searched in the Adobe site AND did a serach ON the site, and found no comparison between the two, or ANY explanation for why X is not an "update".  Perhaps it's just a new & different program that does the same old, but more.

My next step was a google serach, which led me to this site.  No help yet on this issue.
I'm going to WAIT for more information, before I install "X".

AFTER I POSTED THIS ANSWER- I found another site- check this out http://prodesigntools.com/adobe-acrobat-x-10-pro-reader-suite-direct-download-links-ddl.html

Looks like Reader X means "10"  (vs 9 - duh)and would be a new version, but not considered an update.  Seems like PC Mag, according to the above link, liked the "ACROBAT X" at least.

Question is, will an "X" install overwrite 9 or will I need to uninstall 9.
I'm still gonna wait.